# Best way to send commands (mqtt) from a Web(Apache+php+Ajax) hosted in google cloud (Compute Engine - VM) to a specific device (raspberry pi)

Tags: google-cloud-platform

What is the best way to send commands (mqtt) from a Web(Apache+php+Ajax) hosted in google cloud (Compute Engine - VM) to a specific device (raspberry pi)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out IoT Core. There's an admin SDK that allows you to send messages to a registered device.

The communication between IoT Core and the device is done with either HTTP or MQTT.

I wrote a blog that walks you through step by step to do what you're describing needing here:

https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-iot-step-by-step-cloud-to-device-communication-655a92d548ca

Essentially, you'll register your Pi with GCP's IoT Core, which will give it an ID that GCP knows about. Then while it's connected, you can send commands via the Admin SDK. I did it in the blog with a Cloud Function, but you should be able to extrapolate what I did and apply it to PHP. The JavaScript file that's the Cloud Function is here:

https://github.com/GabeWeiss/GCP_Quick_Starts/blob/master/02_basics_gcf/index.js